# Gridview - index range exception when looping through rows

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, webforms, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a problem with a exception below:

> index out of range

I have a GridView where each row has a CheckBox. When I select and item in a DropDown list a certain action is performed depending on the ListItem value.

```
protected void actionSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    GridView gv = Project_GridView;

    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    int SelectValue = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedValue);
    UpdateOp(gv, SelectValue);
    dl_actionSelect.SelectedIndex = 0;
    DataBind();
}
```

This code is run:

```
private void UpdateOp(GridView gv, int SelectValue)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CB_ActionSelect");
        if (check.Checked)
        {
            int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;               
            DataBind();              
            if (!(DBNull.Value == gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value)) //This line throws the exception
            {
                int original_id = Convert.ToInt32(gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);                   
                //Op_Update
                uWeb.Data.ProjLines.Op_Update(SelectValue, original_id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Loops through rows and finds the checked ones. However when more than one checkbox is selected I get:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index is out of range

And the weird part is it seems to be random amount that can successfully run. 1 checked always works, 2+ is rather random sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. Something with the id for the control?

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Project_GridView" runat="server" SkinID="ProdView" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ROWNUMBER" CssClass="gvv"
      DataSourceID="Project_ObjectDataSource" OnRowDataBound="Project_GridView_RowDataBound"
      AllowSorting="true" Width="100%" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="LightGray">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="4%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox id="CB_ActionSelect" Text="" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>                                
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: what line of code is the exception thrown on?

Comment: why do you have `int rowIndex` and do not use it ? and why do you DataBind(); ? I think on DataBinde you lose your actual RowIndex.

Comment: Added comment to the line that throws the exception. the rowindex was used for debbuging. Can't recall exactly why the databind is there, it had something to do with missing data in rows. I will get back to you once i tried to remove it again.

Answer (score 0):

You should get it like this:

```
string Id = gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex %= gv.PageSize][0].ToString();
```

Because, the reported error occurs when the GridView's index increases from the row count.